# Visual Studio WinUI3 generated resources.pri configuration

Tags: visual-studio, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

Building a C++ WinUI3 project generates a resources.pri file, is it possible to rename it? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Specify the default resources that your app uses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/specify-default-resources-installed#how-does-this-work),

> Visual Studio launches a tool named `MakePri.exe` to generate a file(`resources.pri`)
> known as a Package Resource Index (PRI), which describes all of your
> app's resources, including indicating which are the default resources.

And

> [The `resources.pri` file at the root of each package is automatically
> loaded when the **ResourceManager** is instantiated.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/resource-management-system#package-resource-index-pri-file)

Perhaps you need to [create yourself PRI file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/compile-resources-manually-with-makepri) and then [load it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.resources.core.resourcemanager.loadprifiles?view=winrt-22000).